# android getText(int resId) implementation

Tags: android, methods, implementation

I need to see implementation of `getText(int resId)` method. This method is defined as final in abstract class `Context.java` and I've searched implementation in `ContextWrapper.java` and `ContextThemeWrapper.java` but I could't find any implementation. Can somebody post a ling to this method implementation? I've looked on netmite.com for classes implementations. Thanks

Comment: If the method is `final` in Context.java, then its implementation must be in Context.java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is implementation of `getText()` in [`Context.java`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/content/Context.java#L271). Class is abstract but it has implementation of this method.

```
public final CharSequence getText(int resId) {
    return getResources().getText(resId);
}
```

Implementation of [`Resources.getText()`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/content/res/Resources.java#L242):

```
public CharSequence getText(int id) throws NotFoundException {
    CharSequence res = mAssets.getResourceText(id);
    if (res != null) {
        return res;
    }
    throw new NotFoundException("String resource ID #0x"
                                + Integer.toHexString(id));
}
```

Implementation of [`AssetManager.getResourceText()`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/content/res/AssetManager.java#L148):

```
final CharSequence getResourceText(int ident) {
    synchronized (this) {
        TypedValue tmpValue = mValue;
        int block = loadResourceValue(ident, (short) 0, tmpValue, true);
        if (block >= 0) {
            if (tmpValue.type == TypedValue.TYPE_STRING) {
                return mStringBlocks[block].get(tmpValue.data);
            }
            return tmpValue.coerceToString();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Upd:** As mentioned by @zapl `loadResourceValue()` is native and can be found in [`android_util_AssetManager.cpp`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/jni/android_util_AssetManager.cpp#L682).

Answer (score 0):

ICS - frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/res/AssetManager.java

```
/**
 * Retrieve the string value associated with a particular resource
 * identifier for the current configuration / skin.
 */
/*package*/ final CharSequence getResourceText(int ident) {
    synchronized (this) {
        TypedValue tmpValue = mValue;
        int block = loadResourceValue(ident, (short) 0, tmpValue, true);
        if (block >= 0) {
            if (tmpValue.type == TypedValue.TYPE_STRING) {
                return mStringBlocks[block].get(tmpValue.data);
            }
            return tmpValue.coerceToString();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

`loadResourceValue()` is native and defined in frameworks/base/core/jni/android_util_AssetManager.cpp